# Pandas logical indexing on a single column of a dataframe to assign values

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I am an R programmer and looking for a similar way to do something like this in R:

```
data[data$x > value, y] <- 1
```

(basically, take all rows where the x column is greater than some value and assign the y column at those rows the value of 1)

In pandas it would seem the equivalent would go something like:

```
data['y'][data['x'] > value] = 1
```

But this gives a SettingWithCopyWarning.

Equivalent statements I've tried are:

```
condition = data['x']>value
data.loc(condition,'x')=1
```

But I'm seriously confused. Maybe I'm thinking too much in R terms and can't wrap my head around what's going on in Python.
What would be equivalent code for this in Python, or workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is incorrect it should be:

```
data.loc[condition, 'x'] = 1
```

Example:

```
In [3]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(10)})
df
Out[3]:
          a
0 -0.063579
1 -1.039022
2 -0.011687
3  0.036160
4  0.195576
5 -0.921599
6  0.494899
7 -0.125701
8 -1.779029
9  1.216818
In [4]:

condition = df['a'] > 0
df.loc[condition, 'a'] = 20
df
Out[4]:
           a
0  -0.063579
1  -1.039022
2  -0.011687
3  20.000000
4  20.000000
5  -0.921599
6  20.000000
7  -0.125701
8  -1.779029
```

As you are subscripting the df you should use square brackets `[]` rather than parentheses `()` which is a function call. See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)